# Why is size() function of std::string[] array returning an incorrect number of parameters

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

This is a simple 2 line question that I just don't understand.

I just created an array with 3 members, and immediately afterwards, the size is reported as 6. It was working before, but all of sudden changed. I tried cleaning my project.

This is using Visual Studio 2015

```
std::string detectionMethods[3] = { "SQUARE", "CIRCLE", "CIRCLE-SSV" };
int k_size = detectionMethods->length();
```

Thanks,

[Source code and debug screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZcM6.jpg)

Comment: The answer is in what you think `detectionMethods->` is doing. Note that `detectionMethods` is not a pointer, so ask yourself what semantic `->` might have on it.

Comment: Arrays don't have a `size()` or `length()` function on them.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode - please don't do that. Code is text, and you have a text entry box. That's where the code belongs.

Comment: @Useless: You'll notice that he did include the code as text. So you're downvoting because he provided extra information, in the form of an image (displaying information provided by the debugger).

Comment: Makes me laugh at how stackoverflow elitists use their time, probably at work not doing what they are paid to do :)

Comment: Change the definition of `detectionMethods` to `std::array<std::string, 3> detectionMethods = { "SQUARE", "CIRCLE", "CIRCLE-SSV" };`. C-style arrays can be very confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as a member function of a raw array.

---

The sub-expression `detectionMethods` refers to the raw array and decays to a pointer to the first item. The rest, `->length()`, calls a member function of the first item.

---

One easy way to avoid these problems is to use **`std::vector`** instead of a raw array. Your book should be recommending that.

Answer (score 2):

The size of the first string is been returned.

The reason is that a variable which is an array, decays to a pointer to the first element.

So calling `detectionMethods->length()` is the same as calling `detectionMethods[0].length()`